# Can creatures follow me through a portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can creatures from both the Nether and the Overworld follow me through a portal? Is it safe to build a portal in the open, or should it be surrounded in a cobblestone hut to prevent unwanted travellers?

Can regular creatures use the portal to enter the Nether, or can I use it to evade them?

Comment: apparently it's possible, but extremely rare, that a ghast come through a portal and float around in the real world

Comment: it is now possible for all mobs to enter and exit portals in both the overworld and the nether.  check out my answer below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Note:** This answer applies to Minecraft 1.4.1 and earlier. For newer versions see the other answers.

Mobs can not *follow* you through a portal. "Follow" meaning continuing a pursuit by entering the portal after you do and chasing you again once you're on the other side.

Currently, the only danger coming from the existence of a portal is the possibility of a Ghast spawning by it in the "Earth", "Overworld" or whatever we now call the main area of the game. The space they need to spawn there is at least 4x4x4 and, according to Notch, their appearance near the portal is "extremely uncommon".

Comment: ...and if a skeleton kills a ghast while you proudly wield your gold sword of wastefulness, you have won at Minecraft.

Answer (score 24):

As of Minecraft dev version 1.4.2, mobs **have** the ability to travel through portals.  Taken from the wiki:

> - Added new Full-screen toggle to the Video settings.
> - Added new use Vsync toggle in the Video settings.
> - Improved maps
> - Maps now align to a grid, making it easier to create adjacent maps.
> - A compass and paper do now create an empty map
> - An empty map has no data on it until you right click on it. The point on your world - - - where you right clicked it is the map's
>   center
> - A map (with data) can be cloned. Cloned maps are stackable
> - Maps can be zoomed out (but not zoomed in)
> - Stairs now auto-arrange into corners. This is a test and may change based on feedback.
> - **Mobs (and all other entities) can travel through portals.**
> - Fire charges shot from a dispenser or a Blaze create the "fireball" sound effect. Leather armor can be dyed.

---

**Thus to answer your questions above:**

> *Can creatures from the Nether come through a portal?*

Yes, they can. This now applies to all mob entities, including the Wither and Enderdragon bosses.

> *Is it safe to build a portal in the open, or should it be surrounded in a cobblestone hut to prevent unwanted travelers?*

Depends on how you are playing your game (ie game difficulty)

> *Can regular creatures use the portal to enter the Nether, or can I use it to evade them?*

You will not be able to travel through the portal instantaneously, but mobs can. Also, the player now can go through the nether quicker, as of [12w38a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history/Development_versions#12w38a).  As for mob behavior, they do not chase you into the portals.  They may wander into the portals, but not by following the player.

Comment: [Here](http://youtu.be/IedUXLPWrGQ?t=13m49s) is a good example of what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I built a monster trap close to the Overworld side of my Nether gate and spent many nights there.  When I went back into the Nether, I found that numerous skeletons and regular zombies had been going into the gate.  Apparently they could not move once they got there, so the small cobblestone structure housing the Nether side of the gate was jam-packed with skeletons and zombies.  They rapidly pushed me out of the building and killed me....

So Nether gates should probably be protected from monsters by structures on both sides.  I don't think this will stop the occasional appearance of zombie pigmen on the Overworld side, but at least it will stop the Nether side from becoming a skeleton ranch.

Answer (score -1):

I don't now about all or about following, but as of today I was just sitting in my house (portal inside my house) and a zombie pig-man came out of nowhere and attacked me. So I guess any monster standing still long enough could pass through the portal without following you as well, for I had not went though the portal all day, yet here came this zombie after my brains.

Comment: Actually, portals can spawn zombie pigmen. If you're not in the nether (and you're not playing multiplayer), nothing in the Nether moves.

Answer (score -1):

Yes mobs can go through portals but you can't push/force them through easiliy. You can try but it takes a very long time. Unless you are riding the mob.

Comment: You have to dismount first. Nudging passive mobs through is not difficult. As of 1.11, a boat is a good method to get them close enough.