# Can mobs go through portals?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can creatures follow me through a portal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10221/can-creatures-follow-me-through-a-portal)

I'm wondering if mobs can go through portals, to the neither.  That way, I can make a portal in front of my house and have the mobs/zombies/creepers go through it and I wouldn't have to worry about the creatures destroying my house.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but close.

Comment: The questions are from opposite perspectives, but they both garner roughly the same answer.

Comment: If your solution worked, you could assume that mobs could travel *back* through the portal and into your house! **Ghast Strike!**

Comment: @redley: Ghasts are too big to fit through the portals, they're the same width as the whole thing, including the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Minecraft Wiki's [page on portals](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Portal#Trivia):

> If a mob from the real world enters a portal, they will float in the portal as if it was water. Mobs cannot use portals to teleport to the Nether, however they can walk through them.

To sum it up, unfortunately you cannot build a portal to prevent mobs.

If you are playing single player, you can install the [Portal mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/199391-v173-portal-gun-v4-coming-to-smp/) (which is **not** in anyway related to the Nether Portal, but the **game** [portal](/questions/tagged/portal)), you can use an Emancipation Grill, and literally wipe out mobs (including Creepers), at the cost of wiping your inventory.

Comment: Any mob except for wolves because in a loading screen: "Wolves cannot enter the Nether."