# Can cows go through the end portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build a cow farm by my endermen farm. Will cows go through the end portal if I get them there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can creatures follow me through a portal?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10221/can-creatures-follow-me-through-a-portal)

Comment: @MBraedley No, because this guy is asking if they can through the __end__ portal, __not__ the nether portal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, they can.

[Here is a link to a youtube video showing it happening.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psg2PfvERtY)

This is also referenced in [this wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Portal)

> Mobs will enter the portal (As well as the exit portal) similar to the player.

Comment: We didn't see any of the mobs on the other side of the portal though.

Comment: @Gigazelle Well, I can confirm that they will go to the other side of the portal.

Comment: This video shows absolutely nothing, just from me clicking on it. After watching through the whole thing, it just shows the mobs falling through the portal to the lava and then dying.

Comment: From [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/End_Portal) -- **Mobs will enter the portal (As well as the exit portal) similar to the player.**

Answer (score 6):

Yes, any mob/creature can go through the end portal.

Answer (score 2):

Any mob creature or entity can throe nether/end portals. This includes animals, arrows, ect. Ps. It is trivial to Know that the end portal is instant.